# jquery ui ajax tab using aria-control instead of url

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

In jquery-ui 1.10.3 the url method had been replaced with aria-control method.

I can't work out how to use it.

I am trying to load data from a file called action.php

action.php file sends the message "Contents from the server"

I need to place it in the first of three tabs.

It does not work. I get the following message displayed on the chrome console

Uncaught Error: no such method 'aria-controls' for tabs widget instance

I have the following code.

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">Contents of first tab.</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">Contents of the second tab</div>
        <div id="tab3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">Contents of the third tab</div> 
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $("#tabs").tabs()
                .tabs("aria-controls", 0, "action.php")
                .tabs("load", 0);
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying for 4-5 hours to figure this out for my own project. I finally found a solution that works, however I don't think it is how it was intended by the developers:

```
    $("#tabs ul li a").each(function(index){
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                url = "pageone.php?q="+parameter
                break
            case 1:
                url = "pagetwo.php?q="+parameter
                break
            case 2:
                url = "pagethree.php?q="+parameter
                break
        }        
        $(this).attr('href',url)
    })
```

I've seen some posts where it is stated that one should change aria-controls property to the desired url. I tried that as well, but it seems that the tabs function references aria-controls when navigating between tabs, so changing it only gave me a "Mismatching fragment identifier" error.

**Update:** As the OP didn't need the ability to use parameters or change urls programatically, this would be sufficient for the HTML:

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" aria-controls="tab1"><a href="action.php">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-controls="tab2"><a href="action.php">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" aria-controls="tab3"><a href="action.php">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
    <div id="tab2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div>
    <div id="tab3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"></div> 
</div>
```

Then of course the obvious initialization of tabs:

```
$("#tabs").tabs()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply aanders77. That is a good work around. However,  I would still be grateful if somebody would tell me how aria-control is used?

Comment: You're welcome :) Come to think of it, your project only needs to reference static url's with no additional parameters. Couldn't you then just do `<li aria-controls="action.php">...</li>`?

Comment: Thank you again aanders77 for replying. I don't understand what you are saying. If I do <li aria-controls="action.php">...</li> how do I use it in the jquery program. Could you explain furthur please.

Comment: Oops, I meant your anchors <a>, not the <li>'s. Anyways, you don't use it in jquery, you just add aria-controls to the <a>'s in your html, like this: `<a href="#tab2" aria-controls="action.php">Tab 2</a>` Haven't tested it, but it should work :)

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me again aanders77 I tried your suggestion and it makes no difference. Nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry Laurence. This will work, given that you have an action.php file in the same folder as the html file: http://jsfiddle.net/QyRhn/ (Won't actually work in the fiddle though, because there is no action.php)

Comment: Thank you aanders77 I made my code the same as you have at jsfiddle and it worked. Would you like to copy and paste your solution from jsfiddle. Then I will click on the tick so that you get the credit points.